# Are spaces allowed after a backslash to continue a line (in C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, macros

When using `\` to continue a line, are spaces allowed *after* the backslash (on the same line)?

Comment: Space after \ is not allowed. The compiler I am using also used to show error when I mistakenly do this.

Comment: Note that GCC and Clang emulating GCC do permit white space after a backslash — but in doing so goes against the standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A new-line character should go immediately after a backslash. The C++ standard (`N4140`) states:

> **2.2 Phases of translation**
> ....
>
> Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted,
> splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source
> line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice.

(The C standard has the same rules in **5.1.1.2 Translation phases**.)

Comment: Please add source of quote.

Comment: @Adrian Errr.... C++ standard? Any version, as it is carryover from C.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot does this rule apply also to GNU `make`?

Comment: @Adrian - That's a completely separate question.  For the sake of future readers, I'd recommend asking it as it's own question, not in the comments of an answer.

Comment: @Adrian This would be a second question, as C/C++ rules and `make` rules are not related and all similarities are coincidental. Actually answer would be the almost same here too, just quoting other reference.

Comment: The backslash line continuation in `make` and the Bourne derivative shells is unlikely to be a coincidence, not related to the C preprocessor, given that those programs are written in C.

Comment: Lint should flag this. Some compilers might let you get away with this but it's better to code to the standards. Sooner or later you'll work with a compiler that will kick this back to you.